# Customer Session Generation

Tags: magento-1.7, customer

I want to keep a log of all the customer sessions generated in magento. How is it possible? I am thinking in terms of an event being generated when customer sessions are created. Of course, It will be a custom event. Is there a way?

Comment: Have you investigated the session model yet? It really should not be hard to figure out from there. See `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session.php` (from the top of my head).

Answer (score 2):

The event in question is `customer_session_init`. That is the real session, triggered for every visitor to the site.
Should you actually only be looking to track customers logging in try the event `customer_login` instead.

Answer (score 1):

you might be under given code is may useful to you and you can get some batter idea to generate event from that.

```
/* Check if the customer is logged in or not */

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {

/* Get the customer data */
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
/* Get the customer's full name */
$fullname = $customer->getName();
/* Get the customer's first name */
$firstname = $customer->getFirstname();
/* Get the customer's last name */
$lastname = $customer->getLastname();
/* Get the customer's email address */
$email = $customer->getEmail();
}
```